# Simple algebra that is not a simple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Maybe this question is trivial, however I'm not acquainted with non-commutative stuff.

[Here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Simple_algebra) it's written that a simple algebra may not be a simple ring.

The definition of simplicity are the usual ones (no proper two-sided ideals different from $0$). Furthermore, neither the algebra nor the ring are assumed to be unital or associative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_algebra), the definition of simple algebra also requires that the product is not uniformly zero.

Comment: @Bey This definition is different. The problem is that in the link the author says that ideals of algebras and ideals of rings are different.

Comment: I'm confused by what you write in the third paragraph. I think the algebras are assumed to be *associative*, just not *commutative*, right?

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn I don't remember my motivation for asking this question, but the link mentioned above seems to be talking about non-associative algebras as well. It's kind of standard to assume that "algebra" means "associative algebra". In any case, I would be happy with an example of a simple associative algebra which is not an simple (associative) ring if such thing exists.